# How can I create one s3 bucket for `serverless` deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I am using `serverless` deploy my infra to AWS. Each time I change the stack name, a new s3 bucket is created to serve deployment archive data. It ends up to create 90 buckets in my account. Is there a way to let `serverless` use one s3 bucket and create one folder for each stage or stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the same S3 bucket https://medium.com/serverlessguru/how-to-reuse-an-aws-s3-bucket-for-multiple-serverless-framework-deployments-d1673d3d8259 .